# Is it OK to combine several email records (GSuite + Amazon SES)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-workspace

Just to be clear, is it ok for me to do this:

- Continue using Gmail (GSuite) for my business domain (email address);
- Also allow Amazon SES to work using the same email (by adding MX, TXT and CNAME) records?

In other words, can I have both and will both work w/out issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, with no issues at all.  We do this regularly; all our inbound and day-to-day user mail is handled by GSuite, but we send marketing and transactional mails through SES.

When you validate your domain with SES you’ll receive a set of DNS records to insert in to your zonefile. One of those will be an MX record that will look something like

```
10 inbound-smtp.regionInboundUrl.amazonaws.com
```

To have GSuite or another provider handle your incoming (and some outgoing) mail, simply do not create that MX record.

The other DNS records (DKIM, SPF etc) are best practice for sending emails as, at a very high level, they prove to the receiving server that the server that is delivering the message to them is authorized by the domain to send mail on its behalf.

From a practical perspective, sending mail from many places isn’t really an issue, but receiving mail at multiple places isn’t really possible.

Comment: Thanks @hepalump, so to be clear you'd recommend to NOT add the MX Record for Amazon? You mention "To have GSuite or another provider handle your incoming (and some outgoing) mail, simply do not create that MX record" hence my reiteration - thanks

Comment: Thats correct... If you want another service to handle incoming mail, just don’t add the SES inbound server to your DNS, and this no inbound mail will be routed there. Of course, if you don’t have any MX records all mail to the domain will bounce.

Comment: Worth noting this is a very common practice; imagine having an email sending application for bulk email like “mautic”. You’ll send your bulk mail from mautic using SES, but your users normal day-to-day mail would be managed and sent by GSuite or Outlook or whatever other service.

Comment: Wow - you've been really helpful thanks @hephalump. Funnily enough, this is exactly to do with Mautic! I am in the process of setting it up! Your last comment is 100% what I was really hoping to hear - thanks again!

Comment: Awesome! Glad your issue is resolved and I was able to assist!